# Concurrency issue with a local hashmap

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I have a method that receives an `Object ob` as parameter.
This method has a local `HashMap<String, String> mp` which is filled with the fields of `ob`, it also calls other methods passing `ob` and `mp` as parameters.

The problem is that sometimes `mp` gets filled with fields of distinct `ob` objects.

I think `mp` is experiencing concurrency problems,
What is the best way to synchronize `mp`knowing that it's being filled locally and being passed as parameter to various methods to get filled as well.

I don't have or control threads, the application is deployed in weblogic server, so it gets called through webservices, so a lot of calls

Comment: Concurrency wont cause filling mp withe ob objects unless there's an code that explicitly does that. Code would be helpful!!!

Comment: Why do you "think" this is happening due to concurrency issue ?

Comment: @GingerHead Basically because you're describing code instead of showing it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GingerHead because at least you need to include some code no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases, you have

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>
```

Details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

In short, ConcurrentHashMap works by having separated blocks that would be locked independently, so no other threads can access it until work is done (but can access other blocks at that time). Default block size is 16. More about it [here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-concurrenthashmap-works-in-java-internal-implementation.html).

Now, you must understand map sizes in order to talk about filling it up. Default size is 16. But, there is a load factor of 0.75, that means, when map is 75% full, it will resize to double of previous size, that means, creating new array new Set of keys and then copy everything to it (when I say new Set, I mean same logic for resize in it). Now, if you fill it up fast, that means a lot of copying and for larger sizes, it takes time, so its better to give it a large initial size at the beginning, like:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> mp = new ConcurrentHashMapy<>(someLargeSize);
```

Let `someLargeSize` be the order of something you expect or at least near it, so you decrease resizing to minimum. Dont touch load factor, it will just decrease performance, 75% is ok.

And btw., max size of HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap (and HashSet, and ArrayList, or any array based Data Structure) in Java is `1,073,741,824`, since the `array[]` is in background, DS in Java are mostly just wrappers with specific functions for it, but I doubt you will ever reach this limit, since for objects that contains some strings or anything else, you need a lot of GB of RAM for it.

Comment: added answer to your question, after "Details here"

Comment: Its inner implementation, it works perfect, don't worry about it. I worked with web services that would handle large traffic over ConcurrentHashMap within ConcurrentHashMap (caching system) and worked great, no problems with threads.

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic Keep in mind that you are talking about the old, striped lock version of `ConcurrentHashMap`. In Java 8, its implementation was changed significantly (details can be found here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java). But yes, `ConcurrentHashMap` for  the win!